# Can I use the Windows 8.1 Pro Upgrade Student Discount to do a full install on a PC I am building?

Tags: windows-8.1, build

I would like to install Windows 8.1 Pro on my PC I am building from parts. I am a student, and, after I noticed the student discount, looked into it. It claims to be for an upgrade, but is it possible to use it for a full install on the PC I am building? Money is tight (being a student and what-not), so this would help a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Study the offer carefully.

Comment: Students often get the Microsoft Software for free, except Office.

Comment: Sadly, my school does not offer any way to get Windows for free. I will be sure to study the offer again.

Comment: If money being tight is your issue, you can usually buy a legal copy of Windows on eBay or other sites from people who did not have a need for all of the license keys that came with their purchase (usually you get more than one...).  I've seen as low as $45 on there, still in original shrink wrap.  In any case, as this question deals more with legality rather than a technical issue, it's probably off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does offer [a full version](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-8.1-Pro-for-Students/productID.288769600) (i.e. not upgrade) of Windows 8.1 Pro for students.

Answer (score 0):

If it's windows 8.1 "pro pack" (the only 8.1 "upgrade" I know of) then the answer is no as this is the upgrade from windows 8.1 to 8.1 pro. If it's windows 8.1 pro "full" or "system builder" then the answer is yes. I believe it can only be one of these three for windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [this](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Windows-8-Pro-Upgrade-%E2%80%93-Student-Offer/productID.264954100), then not according to Microsoft:

> To install Windows 8 Pro, you must be running Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 Consumer Preview, or Windows 8 Release Preview.